# Input password when prompted - Python

Tags: python, passwords, subprocess

I have the following Python script that will open a program and I need then to enter a password when prompted. However, I can't make it work...

```
# open program
import os
DDS_filepath = 'C:/Users/AAless01/Desktop/MX - Media Explorer.dds'
os.startfile(DDS_filepath)

# input password    
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(['server', 'stop'], stdin=PIPE)
proc.communicate(input='password')
```

Any idea on how I can go about it? No problem if I hard code the password in the script since I'm the only one who's got access to it.

Comment: What goes wrong? Are you just asking how to prompt for a password? That's the `getpass` module.

Comment: i'm basically accessing a program that when opens up asks for a password. So I want to input the password (which I know because it's mine) just after I do the the os.startfile

Comment: If you hardcode your password in your example... that works?

Comment: Nope. That's what I'm trying to find out. A way to enter the password in the box that opens up once I start the program... Say my password is 'password' for the sake of it...

Comment: If this is a GUI that raises a dialog for a password, there may not be a lot you can do about it. Have you read the app documentation to see if there is a command line option you can use?